# System.out.println("Hello World");

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I've got a javascript for my website, but I want some changes in it. Here you see the javascript working

Here's the javascript, the rest you can find in the fiddle:

```
var state = document.ready(function () {});
```

Comment: Use better data structure: http://jsfiddle.net/4MSLJ/1/

Comment: Either attach the script to the .onready handler, or move the entire script tag to the end of the body of the document.

Comment: What should I do if i want it as an external script?

Comment: Attach everything to _document.onready = function() { //all the code }_

Comment: Sorry, use _window.onload_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible! **Edit**: (Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MSLJ/4/) illustrating such.)

There are several solutions.

At the moment, you are using "input".value to set the value of the *input* elements.

Utilizing plain old JavaScript, you could instead do:

```
var someDiv = document.getElementById("someDiv");

someDiv.innerHTML = capital[i]; //or whatever you want to put in there
```

(*Note*: You can use *.textContent* instead of *.innerHTML*, but the latter works in older versions of IE.)

Utilizing jQuery, you could something like:

```
$('#someDiv').html(capital[i]);

//or

$('#someDiv').text(capital[i]);
```

To put this stuff inside your HTML doc and have it working, do this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <!-- all relevant tags -->
        <script>
            //all the script stuff
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- all the html -->

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show me how I can apply this to my javascript? I'm a dumbass when it comes to Javascript haha

Comment: Yeah I'll post a jsfiddle, give me a sec

Comment: [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MSLJ/4/)

Comment: Thank you very very much!! But why doesn't it work when I save it as a HTML Document and open it in Chrome?

Comment: You need to put the script in the head tag, or as an external script.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show you.

Comment: Yeah I did that, but I didn't realize you used jQuery, so I hadn't put the jquery in the head. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: I didn't use jQuery.  It is selected on the fiddle, but no jQuery code was actually used :)  No problem.

Comment: oh so it has to work without jquery in the head?

Comment: Did you export it from jsfiddle?  Regardless, I have [updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MSLJ/7/), and jQuery is now **not** selected.  Do whatever you had been doing with the updated fiddle, and it should work.

Comment: I'll edit my question

Comment: I have posted my whole HTML in my question, I've saved it, opened it in Chrome but it doesn't work

Comment: Is it because of the doctype?

Comment: No, it's not because of the doctype. The DOM never got a chance to load.  Either put the script in the window.onload event as a function, or move the entire script tag to the end of the body.

Answer (score 1):

You should improve your data structure, HTML markup, and avoid unnecessary loops.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4MSLJ/5/)

JS:

```
var data = [
    {
        state: "Alabama",
        capital: "Montgomery",
        date: "December 14, 1819",
        flower: "Camellia",
        bird: "Yellowhammer"
    },
    {
        state: "Alaska",
        capital: "Juneau",
        date: "January 3, 1959",
        flower: "Forget-me-not",
        bird: "Willow Ptarmigan"
    },
    {
        state: "Arizona",
        capital: "Phoenix",
        date: "February 14, 1912",
        flower: "Suguaro Cactus Blossom",
        bird: "Cactus Wren"
    },
    {
        state: "Arkansas",
        capital: "Little Rock",
        date: "June 15, 1836",
        flower: "Apple Blossom",
        bird: "Mockingbird"
    },
    {
        state: "California",
        capital: "Sacremento",
        date: "September 9, 1850",
        flower: "Golden Poppy",
        bird: "California Valley Quail"
    },
    {        
        state: "Colorado",
        capital: "Denver",
        date: "August 1, 1876",
        flower: "Mountain Columbine",
        bird: "Lark Bunting"
    },
    {
        state: "Connecticut",
        capital: "Hartford",
        date: "January 9, 1788",
        flower: "Mountain Laurel",
        bird: "Robin"
    },
    {
        state: "Florida",
        capital: "Tallahassee",
        date: "March 3, 1845",
        flower: "Orange Blossom",
        bird: "Mockingbird"
    },
    {
        state: "Georgia",
        capital: "Atlanta",
        date: "January 2, 1788",
        flower: "Cherokee Rose",
        bird: "Brown Thrasher"
    },
    {
        state: "Hawaii",
        capital: "Honolulu",
        date: "August 21, 1959",
        flower: "Red Hibiscus",
        bird: "Nene (Hawaiian Goose)"
    },
    {
        state: "Idaho",
        capital: "Boise",
        date: "July 3, 1890",
        flower: "Syringa",
        bird: "Mountain Bluebird"
    },
    {
        state: "Illinois",
        capital: "Springfield",
        date: "December 3, 1818",
        flower: "Violet",
        bird: "Cardinal"
    }
];

function showInfo() {
    var page = document.getElementById('spelers'),
        choice = this, // or document.getElementById('spelerslijst')
        d = data[choice.selectedIndex - 1] || {capital: '',date:'',flower:'',bird:''},
        outputs = page.getElementsByTagName('output');
    outputs[0].innerHTML = d.capital; // or page.getElementsByClassName('capital')[0].innerHTML
    outputs[1].innerHTML = d.date;    // or page.getElementsByClassName('date')[0].innerHTML
    outputs[2].innerHTML = d.flower;  // or page.getElementsByClassName('flower')[0].innerHTML
    outputs[3].innerHTML = d.bird;    // or page.getElementsByClassName('bird')[0].innerHTML
}
document.getElementById('spelerslijst').onchange = showInfo;
```

HTML:

```
<form name="spelers" id="spelers">
    <p>Selecteer een speler: 
        <select id="spelerslijst" name="spelerslijst" size="1">
            <option value="">Select ----></option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
        </select></p>
    <p>Capital: <output class="capital" for="spelerslijst"></output></p>
    <p>Admitted On: <output class="date" for="spelerslijst"></output></p>
    <p>State Flower: <output class="flower" for="spelerslijst"></output></p>
    <p>State Bird: <output class="bird" for="spelerslijst"></output></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: How can I apply the onDomready in my HTML?

Comment: @user3024879 Not easy if you don't use a library. Better use `onload` or call your function in a `<script>` element just before closing `</body>`.